# Vim autocmd E488: Trailing characters

Tags: vim

This  line in my vimrc produce the error in the title

```
autocmd CursorMovedI *.html :<C-x><C-u>
```

How I can make it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:autocmd` accepts commands for ex mode, don’t try to feed it normal-mode commands. Correct syntax is probably

```
autocmd CursorMovedI *.html :execute "normal! \<C-x>\<C-u>"
```

or

```
autocmd CursorMovedI *.html :call feedkeys("\<C-x>\<C-u>", 'n')
```

(`:` is not really required, but I use it to separate executed commands from execution conditions). You need to remove `!` from first command or `, 'n'` from the second if you intend to execute a mapping.